# Can I rename my No Man's Sky ship?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I don't like my ship name, but I can't seem to rename it. Is there somewhere in the inventory or journal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was just looking around trying to find out how to do this, and I found out how to do it by accident. When you're in your ship's inventory, if you look up to the top right there's an arrow in a box next to the ship's name. Just click it, it's that simple. I realize this thread is from last year but hopefully it still helps. If you didn't know there ya go!

Answer (score 4):

At present, no, this is not possible. The only way to change the name of your ship is to change your *actual ship* (by purchase or by finding one on a planet) - and then your ship's name would change to the name of the new ship, although obviously you don't get to choose what the new name will be.

Sources: personal gameplay, [that infamous Reddit post](http://www.onemanslie.info/the-original-reddit-post/) about all the stuff that was promised but not delivered in NMS.

Comment: You'll just have to stick with "Jiminogawasamama" like the rest of us...

Comment: Is this still relevant with the latest patch?

Comment: @Burgi I believe so.  I have yet to find a way to change the name of my ship with the foundation update applied.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you can. Just like someone else said, all you have to do is click on the pencil in the right-hand corner of your Starships inventory and type in the name and ta da!

Comment: If an answer is correct, you can simply upvote - you don't need to write a new answer.